# Maps in Flink showing as Generic?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a HashMap in a POJO in **Flink v 1.4.2** such as:

```
class CustomObj{
  public Map<String, String> custTable = new HashMap<>();
  //getter and setter
}
```

**runner.java**

When I do

```
System.out.println(TypeInformation.of(CustomObj.class));
```

I get:

```
PojoType<CustomObj, fields = [custTable: GenericType<java.util.Map>]>
```

Now the problem is why I try to convert a `DataSteam<CustomObj>` into a Table and run an SQL query such as `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE custTable['key'] = 'val'`, it gives me the exception:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Generic ANY types must have a common type information.
```

Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: were you able to solve this? Ran into the same issue on Flink v1.9